# sed or cut? How do I only get column headers from a file?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, ksh

First off, thank you for everyone's help in advance! I've been learning Unix in school and have been doing well up until this most recent homework assignment.

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to approach this particular part in my homework assignment.

I have a headers file which I must separate into two separate files. There are two parts to this part of the assignment:

First, the first two lines of the file go into one file. I did this by doing:

```
head -2 headers > file1
```

However, the next request is to take two column headers (--Regular-- and --Overtime--) and put them into another file...which is what I'm having trouble with.

The header file looks like this:

```
Merry Land Training Academy
Pay Report
Week of June 12, 1999

                --Regular---    --Overtime--    Gross   Net
Employee        Hours   Rate    Hours   Rate    Pay     Pay
```

I know that grep can only match lines that contain the pattern, however how can I remove characters after the last two -- in Overtime?

For example, my grep will return the following:

```
egrep 'Regular' headers

            --Regular---    --Overtime--    Gross   Net
```

I know I could manually do a sed replace of "Gross" and "Net" after doing a grep to remove the words, however I know this is inefficient.

This command will be part of a script which will contain many other processes (which I have been able to do thus far).

In my research online, I know a lot of people recommend using awk, however we have not yet learned this in the course.

Again, thank you in advance. I really look forward to learning from everyone's experience.

Comment: can you give an example of ur input file?

Comment: how about cut, if always in the same position. `cut -c1-47 < file
`

Comment: @Bill Thank you for your reply! The headers file that I mentioned is the input file. I am trying to get the --Regular-- and --Overtime-- column headers into a separate file which can be arbitrarily named (perhaps for this example, file2).

Comment: @BMW - The column headers should be in the same position. I'll definitely take a whack at cut. For some reason, I didn't really think about doing the cut by counting the characters. Thank you! I guess I should egrep the line, save to a temp file, and cut from the temp file?

Comment: If you use cut, use a field count rather than a character count.  And do not save to a temp file; just use a pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think using `sed` would be inefficient?  Certainly piping `grep` to `sed` would be a mistake, but `sed` is pretty good.  You haven't really defined the problem very well, but assuming that you can distinguish a header by the existence of the string `--`, you could simply do:

```
sed -n -e '/--/s/[^-]*$//p' input > output
```

This will take all lines that contain `--` and output everything up to the final `-`.  If you only want to print the first such line:

```
sed -n -e '/--/{s/[^-]*$//p;q;}' input > output
```

Comment: Hi @William, thank you for your help! I apologize for not being clear. I will try to add as much context as possible. I didn't mean sed in itself was inefficient. Just the way I was thinking of doing it. I'll give this a shot. Thank you again!